(Opinionish) Feynman Lectures Exercise: Use principle of virtual work to show the following about $n$ forces in static equilibrium
I would normally not want someone to provide a complete and well-stated solution to an exercise.  In this case, that is exactly what I am seeking.  The following exercise appears in Chapter 2 of the first volume of Exercises in Introductory Physics, by Leighton and Vogt, which is supplemental to The Feynman Lectures on Physics.  My emphasis added:


A body is acted upon by n forces and is in static equilibrium. Use the principle of virtual work to prove that:


a) If $n=1,$ the magnitude of the force must be zero. (A trivial case.)
b) If $n=2,$ the two forces must be equal in magnitude, opposite in direction, and collinear.
c) If $n=3,$ the forces must be coplanar and their lines of action must pass through a single point.
d) For any $n,$ the sum of the product of the magnitude of a force times cosine of the angle $\Delta_{i}$ between the forces and any fixed plane, is zero.
$$\sum_{i}F_{i}\cos\Delta_{i}=0.$$


I know what the PVW is.  I can give hand-wavey answers to all parts.  But I'm not sure what a well-stated solution would be.  Since this is intended for students who ostensibly have never encountered a vector nor the formal concept of torque, I'm not sure how much I should rely on those constructs.  There are also many questions such as:
What is meant by body?  I assume an ideal rigid body, based on intuition.
What, exactly, is meant by two forces acting colinearly?  Shall we restrict ourselves to idealized point contact forces?  What about a body force such as gravity?
If we treat forces as vectors and apply vector algebra, the PVW seems superfluous.
I'm looking for an answer that would appropriately appear in a solutions manual.  It should be elegant, comprehensive and elementary.  I admit that I have not be able to formulate such a solution with which I am satisfied.

Body is collection of matter continuously bounded by volume. It may be rigid, deformable, etc. As it's given in a wiki picture- body can be simply a gas bubble in the water, for example. Collinearity is hard to explain without introducing vectors or linear math at least. Two vectors are said to be collinear if they are described by the same slope $m$ in $y=mx+b$ linear equation. Or to define in terms of angles,- vectors must be separated by $0$ or $\pi$ angle. Though, in a strict terms $\pi$ angle means that vectors are anti-collinear.
